# Application Of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that we have $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\phi,v\in H^1(\Omega)$. Can we prove that

$$\int_{\Omega}(\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla v+\phi v)dx\leq\left(\int_{\Omega}(\nabla\phi)^2+\phi^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{\Omega}(\nabla v)^2+v^2\right)^{1/2} $$

Comment: Assuming everything is real, yes, this is a direct application. Complex requires absolute values.

Comment: All you have to show is that $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_\Omega (f\overline{g}+\nabla f . \overline{\nabla g})dx$ is an inner product, so that $|\langle f,g \rangle|^2 \le \langle f,f\rangle \langle g,g\rangle$

Comment: Also note that if $(.,.)_a$ and $(.,.)_b$ are two different inner products on the same vector space, then  $\langle f,g \rangle = (f,g)_a+(f,g)_b$ is also an inner product. Hence $\langle f,g \rangle = (f,g)+(\partial_x f,\partial_x g)+(\partial_y f,\partial_y g)$ is an inner product (where $(f,g) = \int_\Omega f \overline{g}dx$ is the usual inner product on $L^2(\Omega)$)

Comment: @user1952009 : Technically, the $(\cdot,\cdot)_a$ is not an inner product if it involves the gradient because it may not be positive definite. But positive-definite is not required to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @TrialAndError yes I meant $\langle f,g\rangle = (f,g)_a+(Mf,Mg)_b$ is an inner product if $(.,.)_a,(.,.)_b$ are and $M$ is any linear operator

Comment: @user1952009 : It would good if you would post your solution as an answer. There are too many unanswered questions on the site, and it is encouraged that people post answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is real-valued. Observe by Cauchy-Schwarz we have
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \nu +\phi \nu =& \int_{\Omega}(\nabla\phi, \phi)\cdot(\nabla \nu, \nu)\ dx\\
 \leq&\ \left(\int_\Omega |\nabla \phi|^2+|\phi|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_\Omega |\nabla \nu|^2+|\nu|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}